# How to dynamically add extra input fields in k2 item form

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, extensions, k2

**Problem**

I'm currently working on a form which has to implement a way to create a schedule for a single day. It should use a time for when an event starts, and a description about the events.

The schedule can have varying amount of times/events.

**Idea for solution**

So a solution can be to create a row with dual inputs: one with a time input that defines the hour, and one with a text input that describes the event at that hour.

**Issue with idea to solution**

The problem is that K2 cannot do this natively. It does in fact not even have a time input extra field, let alone a way to link several input together or dynamically adding more rows (that I know of).

**Idea to solve issue + question**

One way to get around this could be to either find one or more plugins that do this (preferably), or to create my own plugin.

1. Does anyone know of existing plugins, or of a different way to deal with those problems?
2. If not, is there some documentation about creating k2 plugins that can be found somewhere?

I have already downloaded [the example plugin](https://getk2.org/extend/extensions/90-example-k2-plugin-for-developers) from getK2's website, but it feels very limited for what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Hi T.P. and welcome. I don't know if there is any such plugin. #2,3 questions are too broad... Actually you have the sample plugin from K2, likely you have the html/js from somewhere else... what else you need? May I ask: Are you skilled enough for diving into this task? Or simply looking for copying/pasting code? If the latter, then I hope you will be lucky enough if someone has this done already and would like to offer it - even so, it still has some custom requirements. If you are skilled enough... then you should present some effort and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: @FFrewin Hi, FFrewin. No, I am not looking or asking for copy/paste code. I was looking for information about pre-existing plugins (if there were such) and for documentation (if there were such) about creating K2 plugins.